# Error during SonarScanner execution of flutter project

Tags: flutter, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

i have installed flutter plugin from [https://github.com/insideapp-oss/sonar-flutter].

got below error while running sonar-scanner:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while running 'flutter analyze --no-fatal-warnings --no-fatal-infos' (exit 1): 64 issues found. (ran in 17.9s)

        at fr.insideapp.sonarqube.dart.lang.issues.dartanalyzer.executable.AnalyzerExecutable.maybeThrowException(AnalyzerExecutable.java:103)
        at fr.insideapp.sonarqube.dart.lang.issues.dartanalyzer.executable.AnalyzerExecutable.analyze(AnalyzerExecutable.java:91)
        at fr.insideapp.sonarqube.dart.lang.issues.dartanalyzer.DartAnalyzerSensor.execute(DartAnalyzerSensor.java:67)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:64)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:88)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:61)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:61)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringModuleScanContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.scan(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:403)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:399)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:368)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.SpringGlobalContainer.doAfterStart(SpringGlobalContainer.java:137)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:71)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:65)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:126)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:81)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62)
```

I am not sure this issue belong from plugin side or from code side, need help!